# Approve Allowance ERC(20)

Tags: solidity, remix, erc-20, erc-20-approve

Can you please tell why do we have to approve ERC20 tokens before sending them?

```
contract Transfer {
    function version1() {
         ERC20(someToken).transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), 122);
     }

    function version2() {
         ERC20(someToken).approve(address(this), 122)
         ERC20(someToken).transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), 122);
     }
}
```

Can't the transferFrom function get the security job done by itself and if not why is it implemented so?

Comment: Would you be OK if I was allowed to transfer from your bank account as much money as I wanted to without asking for your approval?

Comment: Of course not, but there is the second question. Why it's not implemented inside one function, both for approving and transferring, because when you are using transferFrom(), it means that most likely, you are not transferring from the current contract(otherwise, you simply could use transfer() function), so you would need for an approval anyways?

Comment: Because `approve` is executed with your account (using your private key), and `transferFrom` is executed with someone else's account (using his/her private key).